# Can't web scrap html table beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrap IPO table data from here:
https://www.iposcoop.com/last-12-months/

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.iposcoop.com/last-12-months/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
table1 = soup.find("table",id='DataTables_Table_0')
table1_data = table1.tbody.find_all("tr")
table1
```

However, table1 is NonType. Why is that? Any solution? I have read related issues, iframe doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: Because there is no table with ID `DataTables_Table_0` in the source. You're probably looking at the source in your browser, which is not what BeautifulSoup sees. BS does not execute JavaScript, and that table is probably generated dynamically using JS.

Comment: any simple solution to this still using beautifulsoup or selenium?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can grab table data using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='https://www.iposcoop.com/last-12-months'
req=requests.get(url).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(req,'lxml')
table=soup.select_one('.standard-table.ipolist')
table_data =pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(table_data)
```

Output:

```
                 Company  Symbol  ...   Return SCOOP Rating
0                                         Akanda Corp.    AKAN  ...   85.00%          S/O     
1    The Marygold Companies, Inc. (aka Concierge Te...    MGLD  ...    9.50%          S/O     
2                            Blue Water Vaccines, Inc.     BWV  ...  343.33%          S/O     
3            Meihua International Medical Technologies    MHUA  ...  -33.00%          S/O     
4                                        Vivakor, Inc.    VIVK  ...  -49.40%          S/O     
..                                                 ...     ...  ...      ...          ...     
355                Khosla Ventures Acquisition Co. III    KVSC  ...   -2.80%          S/O     
356           Dragoneer Growth Opportunities Corp. III    DGNU  ...   -2.40%          S/O     
357                                        Movano Inc.    MOVE  ...  -43.60%          S/O     
358         Supernova Partners Acquisition Company III  STRE.U  ...    0.10%          S/O     
359                           Universe Pharmaceuticals     UPC  ...  -74.00%          S/O     

[360 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's very efficient

Comment: shorter `table_data = pd.read_html('https://www.iposcoop.com/last-12-months')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

While F.Hoque's answer gives you a solution, it does not seem to answer why your code  throws an error.

You are trying to find a table with the id `DataTables_Table_0`. Opening the [page](https://%27https://www.iposcoop.com/last-12-months%27)  in a browser, you can see that such an element with the given id exists. But if you open the same page after disabling Javascript you can see that the id no longer exists on the table. This id is being assigned by some javascript module.

BeautifulSoup can only fetch the base HTML and it does not run javascript modules. So you have 2 solutions:

1. Use a selector that exists in the base HTML (in this case `.standard-table.ipolist`)
2. Use selenium to run Javascript and fetch the HTML as it is seen in a browser

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this info. very insightful note